# Migrate SQL database from 2014 to 2012 version - mvc codefirst

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, migration, code-first

I'm developing a project with ASP.net-MVC and as it's Model first, it generates the .mdf and .ldf files of database automatically. and database is in version of 2014. when I wanted to upload it on host server they told me that they don't support upper version of 2012. so I need to migrate my data base from 2014 to 2012 version.

my data base is not that much big. and I follow this article 
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2810/how-to-migrate-a-sql-server-database-to-a-lower-version/ 
step by step but no diffrence happend to my database version. its still `Product Version:12.0.2000.8`

really appreciate you'r help. thanks

Comment: In case of you downgrading the DB engine, probably you need to convert/re-save the development DB into corresponding version you want to run, avoiding potential migration issues. Then you can set EF point to 2012 version, ensure you have backups before reconfiguring EF.

Comment: SSMS is a client side software helping you to monitoring your SQL Server instances. If you don't have any SQL Server instance, you need to install one on your host server. SSMS 2012, 2014 or 2016 are all compatible for SQL Server 2012 instances. I never migrate a database from upper version to lower, so cannot help you with that. But I'm sure that the backup is not suitable, because backup file has `.bck` extension and you've raw database files with data `.mdf` and log `.ldf`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto thanks for your help. do you have  any idea how to do this?  I've never heard that its possible to change the version of database which `EFW` generates it. if you know how I will appreciate to tell me how to do this thanks alot

Comment: @MincongHuang thanks for you'r kind help. I was thinking to convert mdf and ldf foles to .bak some how. so do you have any idea how to solve this problem? anyawy you did alot. thank you 100000..0000 times

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto you meant before creating the project change the version of entity frame work?

Comment: @nedaDerakhshesh, you're welcome. The conversion from `.mdf` + `.ldf` to `.bck` might require several steps: DB attachment to SQL Server 2014; backup & export DB; restore backup to SQL Server 2012. Do you think about [link your project to an existing SQL Server instance, and then create a new database?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542)

Comment: I update my answer with a tutorial to build a ModelFirst approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You develop the database based on the Model First, so you have all control in generation /modifying the database.

You needn't to migrate the database, but in visual studio you can re-generate the database in sql server 2012.

To Generate the database in sql 2012, do the same steps  you follow to generate database for sql 2014 in visual studio, just for reminding:

- In the EDMX design surface, right click ->Generate database from the model
  Follow the wizard and create a new connection to sql2012.

At end of the wizard, a new database is created in sql  server 2012.

- Sql script is also auto generated named e.g. model.edmx.sql including all DDL of the Entity and associations,...
- Exute that script within VS, you can select the connection and executing the script in the new database server 2012.
- For the data, you can use the bcp utility or the export wizard in SSMS.

**Update:**

In the Model First approach, you create a diagram that will be automatically converted to a coded model and the model is saved in EDMX (xml file).

If there is no EDMX in the project, it means that you didn't use the ModelFirst approach, but you may used a template of MVC project which auto generate database at the start of the project.

The benefit of the Model First is the ease of change and sync between development Environment and the production for future changes.

You can re-engineer your project and add ModelFirst approach even you created a database.

From there you can re-create the database in the sql server 2012.
I describe step by step tutorial to build your mode:

[Building DataModel from Existing Database in EntityFramework 6 For ModelFirst Approach](https://mohhassan20.wordpress.com/2016/10/12/building-datamodel-from-existing-database-in-entityframework-6-for-modelfirst-approach/)

Comment: yes I need exactly something like this. let me try . I think i'm so close to the answer

Comment: Excuse me I didn't find any 'EDMX' file.I didn't choose anything.  visual studio itself creates everything EFW and also database.  is it possible to give me a step by step guide. thanks.

Comment: In the Model First approach, you create a diagram that will be automatically converted to a coded model and the model is saved in EDMX (xml file). If there is no EDMX in the project, it means that you didn't use Model First approach, but you may used the template in MVC project which auto generate database at start of the project. The benefit of the Model First is the ease of change and sync between development Environment and the production for future changes.

Comment: yes exactly I'm using template . really thank you and also exactly what I was looking for thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Compatibility Level should be set to SQL Server 2012(110) before to following the steps https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2810/how-to-migrate-a-sql-server-database-to-a-lower-version/

To change the compatibility level go to database properties->Options->Compatibility Level

When you run the output script, it should be run on the target server (2012). Backups on recent versions cannot be restored on earlier versions.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did so but still no difference ,but really thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2810/how-to-migrate-a-sql-server-database-to-a-lower-version/)

The setup will change your database from 2014 to 2012.

Comment: thank you so much for your care. I follow all these steps but nothing happens. I checks the version here and each time is the same as before. `https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321185`  I asked also the host server to check it after all these changes but still nothing happend